# php store uploaded path to table and display

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, file-upload

i am new in php... i had created a simple php file upload script given below...

form.php

```
<form action="uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

uploader.php

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
?>
```

my question is i had created a mysql database `account` and a table `student` with 4 field `id, name, age, image` i want store my uploaded image path to these table, and display this image my web page where i want...  have any simple solutions.? with example... sorry im just new in mysql

thanks....

Comment: Ya so simply save the `image_name.extension` in your database, use a while loop to fetch records and you are done...

Comment: can you suggest any simple example code.? its very helpful... thanks

Comment: I'll give you a complete code with explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assumed you have already students in you database and change their profil image

a user must be logged in to upload images so you will use something like $_SESSION['studentid']

```
<?php
$path = "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$path);

$sql = "UPDATE students SET image = '".$path."' WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['studentid'];
mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());

?>
```

later on if you want to display the user image use this query

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT image FROM students WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['studentid'];
$result = mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['image'];
?>
```

Comment: i think this solution for get image from table, but i want store photo to a folder "upload" and use php for display that photo where i want, if direct store to table this file i don't know how can i find this...

Comment: you will have to upload it first to your path and save the path to the database

Comment: @ChaosClown Use `mysqli_()` instead of `mysql_()` ;)

Comment: uhm? why is that? you mean placing misstypes to make it harder to solve ^^

Comment: @ChaosClown go to php manual and read the big red box on `mysql_()` page, they are going to be deprecated, and are no more maintained by the community